# How to use Condtional statements in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to select either "abstract" or "body" tag contains but using below code i get content from both tags in XSLT. If I remove "xsl:if" there is no effect on output.

```
<xsl:template match="document">
<xsl:for-each select="./child::node()">
  <xsl:choose>        
    <xsl:when test="name() = 'abstract'">
      <xsl:call-template name="abstract"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:if test="name() = 'body'">
        <xsl:call-template name="body"/>
    </xsl:if>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:for-each>
```

what changes i have to make in above code?

Comment: What should happen if multiple `abstract` or `body` nodes exist? Is that case important?

Comment: Is there a particular reason that you are using named templates here?  Normally you would have `<xsl:template match="body">` and `<xsl:template match="absract">` and then just use `<xsl:apply-templates select="."/>`

Comment: You require one and not the other? Based on what criteria? Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson there is only one body and abstract node

Comment: @Xtreme_Enigma, if abstract node present then i don't want contents of body node but if abstract node is not present then only i want body node contents

Comment: @Pankaj Surely you have both of them in your xml that is why you are getting this behavior. If both are present what you want to do? You surely do understand that XSLT is not a procedural language right?

Comment: @Xtreme_Enigma if both are present then i want only abstract node contents

Comment: You can have multiple `<when/>` elements in a single `<choose/>`; no need for that nested `<if/>`.

Comment: Please show a complete and reproducible example. In the case of XSLT questions, this means a complete XSLT stylesheet and both XML input and expected output. Help: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the conditionals outside of your for-each

```
<xsl:template match="document">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="abstract">
            <xsl:for-each select="abstract">
                <xsl:call-template name="abstract"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:for-each select="body">
                <xsl:call-template name="body"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

We first test if we have any abstract elements.  If such, we loop over all abstract elements and call the appropriate template.

Otherwise, we loop over the body elements and call the appropriate template.

Your existing xsl is looping over all nodes and for each one checking the node name, and then applying the appropriate template.  The tests are applied on the individual nodes.  There is no checking of the document contents.

The difference here, is that we first test what nodes exist in the document, and then loop only over the ones that we are interested in.

**Alternative Approach**

Assuming that the template named abstract only processes abstract nodes and the template named body only processes body nodes, it is more common to use matching templates instead of named templates, which will allow us to avoid the for-each loop

```
<xsl:template match="document">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="abstract">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="abstract"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="body"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="abstract">
    <!-- Process abstract node here -->
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="body">
    <!-- Process body node here -->
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: @Pankaj In what way is it not working?  You have not provided any sample input document, so I am only able to guess what your input looks like.

Comment: <abstract xmlns="">sectionid="P13"><paragraphd="P14"><text>Objectives: Since blood selenium levels decrease after ischemia and reperfusion injury, and low blood selenium correlates with negative outcome, we designed and performed experiments to determine how selenium distribution is affected by ischemia reperfusion injury. We also examined the metabolic effects of selenide administration.</text></paragraph></abstract>
<body xmlns=""><paragraph id="P22"><text>During many injuries and diseases, tissue is deprived of blood.</text></paragraph>

Comment: this is my input i want only abstract node value but in some XML abstract node is not present that time i used body node contents

Comment: It is working perfectly for me - only processes the abstract node, but if I delete that node, it then processes the body node.  However, it looks like your xml is invalid, but that is hard to tell with it posted into a comment.  You should edit the question to add that and correctly format it.

Comment: In XML,there is an attribute called xmlns because of that it not working correctly. is any way to resolve that.

Comment: @Pankaj That is not exactly an attribute, it is a namespace declaration, and it shouldn't be causing problems here.  You could just remove it.  Please edit your question to contain the sample xml and correctly format it.  It is hard to judge what is going wrong with that posted in a comment, which messes up the formatting.  It looks to be invalid, or structured differently from what you described there.